# iOS 8 Label autoshrink

Tags: ios8

It seems to me, that in iOS 8 auto shrink isn't working. I try to set minimum font scale / minimum font size, but the text after loading remains static. When I run an app on iOS 7 everything is OK.

Comment: do check your labels auto layout settings.. might be this will help http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/24/ios8-day-by-day-day-5-auto-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: I studied it more. It's not working with attributed text.

Comment: can you share some code what you are doing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain text i cannot confirm that problem in iOS 8 but with attributed text i saw the same issue. A workaround was to set the font name and size explicitly programmatically for the label text (not only in storyboard attributes inspector). That way the attributed text size changed accordingly.